# Input type attribute getting removed from the source

Tags: php, html

I am using search form with input field something like:

```
<input type="text" id="s" name="s">
```

But whenever page is loading, `type="text"` is getting removed from the source. I am using `PHP` with `Apache server` to render the page.

I also even tried with a simple html page with no JS and a simple input form but there also the same thing is happening.

Please anybody suggest any solution.

Update: Example code as requested by Witherwind:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Input type attribute test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            button <input type="button"><br>
            checkbox <input type="checkbox"><br>
            color <input type="color"><br>
            date <input type="date"><br>
            datetime <input type="datetime"><br>
            datetime-local <input type="datetime-local"><br>
            email <input type="email"><br>
            file <input type="file"><br>
            hidden <input type="hidden"><br>
            image <input type="image"><br>
            month <input type="month"><br>
            number <input type="number"><br>
            password <input type="password"><br>
            radio <input type="radio"><br>
            range <input type="range"><br>
            reset <input type="reset"><br>
            search <input type="search"><br>
            tel <input type="tel"><br>
            text <input type="text"><br>
            time <input type="time"><br>
            url <input type="url"><br>
            week <input type="week"><br>
            Submit <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Live example: [link](http://indiahelpdesk.in/type1234.html)

Comment: Its happening in simple HTML page also.

Comment: Other input type like `button, checkbox, color, date, datetime, datetime-local, email, file, hidden, image, month, number, password, radio, range, reset, search, submit, tel, time, url, week` are rendering fine

Comment: That's why you have to show us the PHP code.

Comment: Show us a live example please.